# Nginx "Broken pipe" When Debugging Django?

Tags: django, debugging, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Django site that uses Gunicorn and Nginx.  Occasionally, I'll have a problem that I need to debug.  In the past, I would shut down Gunicorn and Nginx, go to my Django project directory and start the Django development server ("python ./manage.py runserver 0:8000"), and then restart Nginx.  I could then insert set_trace() commands and do my debugging.  When I fixed the problem I'd shut down Nginx and then restart Gunicorn and Nginx.  I'm pretty sure this was working.

Recently, though, I've begun having problems.  What happens now is that when I've stopped at a breakpoint, after a couple of minutes the web page that I've stopped on will change and display "404 Not Found" and if I take another step in the debugger, I'll see this error:

```
- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 43742)
```

This happens on my development, staging, and production servers which I'm accessing via their domain names, e.g. "web01.example.com"  (not really example).

What is the correct way to debug my Django application on my remote servers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  First I observed that when I stopped at a breakpoint, the page always timed out after exactly one minute which suggested that the Nginx connection to the web server was timing out if the web server took more than 60 seconds to respond.  I then found an Nginx proxy_read_timeout [directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout) which defines this timeout.  Then it was merely a matter of changing the length of the timeout in my Nginx config file:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.conf
http {
     server {
            ...
            location @django {
                ...
                # Set timeout to 1 hour
                proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
                ...
            }
            ...
     }
}
```

Once you've made this change you need to *reload* Nginx, not restart it, in order to this change to take effect.  Then you start Django as I indicated above and you can now debug your Django application without it timing out.  Just be sure to remove the timeout setting when you're done debugging, reload Nginx again, and restart Gunicorn.

Comment: can i ask, what is the downside of setting this value too high?